# spreadsheet expanding dates, using one function

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Is this possible using a function in excel or google spreadsheet using one formula? No code please.

input:
cell A1 `= "mike "`
cell A2 `= "1/1/13"`

One function in B1 `=somefunction()` that would give me "mike" and the month end of every month up til now (today)?

output:
B1 `= mike 1/31/13`
B2 `= mike 2/28/13`
B3 `= mike 3/31/13`
etc... 
up to

B7 `= mike 7/31/13`

Comment: Do you want functions then instead of code?

Comment: Also, by function do you mean in cell function or are you also including macros, because it'd be extremely simple to do with a macro attached to say a button.

Comment: no macro, Just ONE Function please.

Comment: You can create your own user defined functions, this wiki how might be useful http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel[link]

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way.

```
=$A1&" "&TEXT(DATE(YEAR($A2),MONTH($A2)+COLUMNS($A1:B1),1)-1,"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

text() to format the date right

date(year(),month()+1,1) takes the date given, goes to the start of the next month, and then we subtract a day (-1) to get to the end of the month.

columns() returns the number of columns between the start of an array (stuck at A) and the end(dynamic to wherever the formula is copied)

To adjust this so that it stops showing values when the date is greater than the current month:

```
=IF((DATE(YEAR($A2),MONTH($A2)+COLUMNS($A1:B1),1)-1)<=TODAY(),$A1&" "&TEXT(DATE(YEAR($A2),MONTH($A2)+COLUMNS($A1:B1),1)-1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),"")
```

Be sure to copy this into the cells as far across as you ever expect the range to grow eg. B1,C1,D1,E1.

Comment: +1 For using the COLUMNS call like that. I started googling ways to increment on fill, but this is heaps better.

Comment: I'm confused. I put the formula into B1 and the formula only returns one value: "mike 28/02/2013" ... I need all month ends between 31/1/2013 and 31/7/2013 (current month end) dynamically

Comment: updated the answer with a second version that does this with an if statement. Ensure you copy the formula across your spreadsheet as necessary.

Comment: @RowanC. Thanks for the update but it still doesn't work. the output only gives me one return. It doesn't fill down automatically. I need it to fill down automatically without any copying "the formula across" my spreadsheet. One formula should give me 7 cells of output.